# Django - Automatically change some "terms" in the response text based on settings

Tags: python, django

Let us say that we have two applications, *Foo* and *Bar*, and we use the same backend code for both of them. In our case, we decided to deploy two versions of this code -- one for each application. There are some endpoints where the server would behave slightly differently depending on whether it is running as *Foo* or *Bar*. Some endpoints are also not available for one app. (There are some reasons we are doing it like this). We use a flag in the settings file to determine the server type (*Foo* and *Bar* type).

So far everything is working well, except for one thing: aside from the slight difference in behavior, there are also some *terms* that should be automatically change (translated?) -- both in the templates and in the REST API -- depending on the server type. For instance, in the page header, *Foo* would display `"Welcome to Foo"`, and *Bar* should display `"Welcome to Bar"`.

The question is, how do I achieve this?

Comment: You just need to make code parts that rely on your `settings.SERVER_TYPE`

Comment: Yes. But I was thinking if maybe there's a cleaner way of doing it, like something that would mimic the localization approach.